# I'd like to play gifs on mouse over in a different location

Tags: jquery, html, gif

I am looking to write small paragraphs of information with key words in them. When the Key word is moused over the gif would play in a pop up box - see image (http://imgur.com/SK37Ikc)

an example of what I am talking about in action (sort of) is https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaAvm.jpg look at the comments and mouse over the gif one (#8 or so). I want to do the same thing. I have very limited programming experience and it doesn't need to be built out into an entire webpage just something I can put in a small section on another page.

Thank you for any help in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function(){
$('#img_wrap').mouseover( function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('animated', 'static');
    })
})

</script>

<style>
.animated #static, .static #animated {
    display: none;
}
.animated #animated, .static #static {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="img_wrap" class="static">
    Big long write up would go here with various key words being spaced throughout that I would like to play gifs on mouse over.
    <img id="animated" src="http://i.imgur.com/MgYashD.gif" alt="">
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MG5c5/) with a popup video. I assumed video based on your link example.

But when you say "gif" do you just mean an animated gif?

Here is an animated gif [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MG5c5/1/).

JS

```
$('.mouseoverme').hover(
    function(){
        $('.hiddendiv').css('display', 'block');
        $('.hiddendiv').html(
            "<img src='https://secure.mooseintl.org/FRUAdmin/images/gears_animated.gif' />"
            );
                       },
    function(){
        $('.hiddendiv').css('display', 'none');
               }
```

### );

An example keywords in a text.

```
<p> We the <span id='people'>people</span> in order to form a more perfect <span id='union'>union</span></p>
```

Then just use the id to do a .hover.

Comment: The animated gif Fiddle is very close to what I'd want. Essentially that but with text instead of the block, then the ability to have multiple gifs able to be called up out of the same paragraph based on keywords

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the issue of "key words" -just put them in a span with an id. But now I'm confused. In your initial question you stated "gif would play in a popup". What do you want? Text or .gif?

Comment: The idea is to have a paragraph of Text that when you .mouseover certain words in it -> gif pops up. So essentially this thing http://jsfiddle.net/MG5c5/23/ but instead of the two red boxes, I'd mouse over a word to call up everything instead of the box

Comment: This is what I've got based on that not sure what I am doing wrong though -


<div id="img_wrap" >
Stargate opening from Jim but great scouting from Bomber makes sure he is safe and goes for a 3 rax 
<span id="img_keyword"> pressure </span> which is held by double photon overcharges. Jim builds his Colossus/Phoenix army but Bomber won't have it and pushes in and focuses Colossus with Vikings for the win.
<img id="pic"  src="http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/2-08-2014/HJqgCc.gif" alt="">

Comment: I just put spans around two words, and changed the background from red to font bold - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/MG5c5/29/

Comment: Perfect, you helped so much! Wish I could upvote you haha. My next project is to have the GIFs display over their text or in a set location not sure which would be harder. As it is though this is a massive help thank you!